# Is there a way of deferring React component updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

We have a large grid rendering lots of expensive components. To reduce the load on the page we use a vitualized list and only render the visible portion at any given moment. This means that whenever someone scrolls, there is flash of white as the components previously outside of the visible area render for the first time.

To get around this we can define an "overscan" area - an amount of items that gets rendered around the visible area that is immediately visible on scroll. Unfortunately that means that these components are now updating alongside page state, which is in our case an expensive operation for any reasonable amount of overscan.

I was thinking one way to resolve this would be to defer the update/render lifecycle of components outside of the visible area to when the call stack clears, utilizing a `setTimeout`, or perhaps using a `requestIdleCallback`. I have not been able to find a way of doing this in React 16/17 - any ideas?

Comment: *"Unfortunately that means that these components are now updating alongside page state..."* By "these components," do you mean the ones in overscan?

Comment: Instead of writing this code yourself could you use something like AGGrid which has all of this built in? (Not a shill for AGG, promise, but it was a Godsend in my last job).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the components a property telling them whether they're in overscan or not, and have [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) return `false` if `inOverscan` is `true` for both the previous and current props (or if using function components, [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)'s comparison function would return `true` if `inOverscan` is `true` for both the previous and current props).

Here's an example:

```js
const { useState, Component } = React;

class Example1 extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return !nextProps.inOverscan || !this.props.inOverscan
    }
    
    render() {
        const {inOverscan, value} = this.props;
        return <div>
            Example1 - inOverscan = {String(inOverscan)} - value = {String(value)}
        </div>;
    }
}

const Example2 = React.memo(
  ({inOverscan, value}) => {
        return <div>
            Example2 - inOverscan = {String(inOverscan)} - value = {String(value)}
        </div>;
  },
  // Beware that the return value for `memo`'s comparison
  // function is the opposite of the one for
  // `shouldComponentUpdate`
  (prevProps, nextProps) => nextProps.inOverscan && prevProps.inOverscan
);

const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const [inOverscan1, setInOverscan1] = useState(true);
    const [inOverscan2, setInOverscan2] = useState(true);

    const incrementValue = () => setValue(value => value + 1);

    return <div>
        <div>
            App - value = {String(value)}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Increment value" onClick={() => setValue(value => value + 1)} />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={inOverscan1} onChange={(e) => setInOverscan1(e.target.checked)} />
                Example1 in overscan
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={inOverscan2} onChange={(e) => setInOverscan2(e.target.checked)} />
                Example2 in overscan
            </label>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <Example1 inOverscan={inOverscan1} value={value} />
        <Example2 inOverscan={inOverscan2} value={value} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you run that, you'll see that initially, incrementing `value` doesn't re-render `Example1` or `Example2`. But if you untick the box for one of them so it's not considered "in overscan" anymore, it updates to match the current `value` and follows updates to `value`, while the one that's still "in overscan" doesn't.

Comment: I thought about this - as the components would need to re-render as they enter the visible area I have a strong feeling that there would be a palpable delay until the user sees the final render, especially if we have something like 100 cells scroll into view at once, echoing the original issue. Still, it might be a better UX than what we have at the moment, doesn't hurt to try - thanks

Comment: @styke - Yeah, give it a go. Updating what's shown in the component is probably faster than showing it originally (usually less reflow), but it depends a lot on the components themselves. But you've given me an idea for the MVC lib I'll never actually write (built-in configurable debouncing). :-D

Comment: This actually made a big improvement in our app counter to my initial feeling. Thanks for helping this along!