# React – Passing event from child component to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am new to React.js so I apologise if this is a foolish question or one that has been asked before. I have a component tree structured as such: **form (grandparent) → input field (parent) → button (child)**

I am attempting to listen for a click (onClick event handler) of the **button** and have that trigger a function at the level of the **form** (ideally also passing the content of the input field to the form).

Is there a general method to do this or a specific part of the documentation I should read? I know I can pass data from the parent to child via props, is there a reverse of this?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). It's impossible for an `input` field to have a `button` in it if you really mean `input` and `button`. So an example would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195096/18200347) earlier today.

Comment: in terms of docs, it sounds like this could help: [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) and [free code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-lifting-state-up-in-react/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have the form pass a function to the child as a prop, and have the child pass that function on to the button as a prop, like this:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const onClick = () => {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    };
    return <Parent onClick={onClick} />;
};

const Parent = ({onClick}) => {
    return <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Click Me</button>;
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

For that simple example, I've just recreated the function every time `Example` is rendered, but there are times you don't want to do that, because it makes `Parent` and `button` both re-render any time anything in `Example` changes. You might use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to avoid passing a new function to `Parent` (and thus to `button`) every time. (That would only help if `Parent` and any other intermediate components were memoized, as with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or [for `class` components] [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) or a component using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).) More about that in my other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293410/157247) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69675835/157247).

Here's something demonstrating how changing something unrelated to the click handler causes unnecessary re-rendering of `Parent`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(
            () => setCounter(c => c + 1),
            800
        );
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
    const onClick = () => {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    };
    return <div>
        <div>
            Counter: {counter}
        </div>
        <Parent onClick={onClick} />
    </div>;
};

const Parent = ({onClick}) => {
    console.log(`Parent rendering...`);
    return <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Click Me</button>;
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

And an example that memoizes `onClick` and uses `React.memo` to make `Parent` not re-render when nothing significant (to it) changes:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setInterval(
            () => setCounter(c => c + 1),
            800
        );
        return () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
    }, []);
    const onClick = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    }, []);
    return <div>
        <div>
            Counter: {counter}
        </div>
        <Parent onClick={onClick} />
    </div>;
};

const Parent = React.memo(({onClick}) => {
    console.log(`Parent rendering...`);
    return <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Click Me</button>;
});


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I apologise for not including the code; I couldn't figure out how to extricate something reproducible without including the whole project. Passing functions as props has worked perfectly. (In reply to your above comment regarding placing a button inside an input, I have a created a React component that wraps an input and an absolutely-positioned button in a parent div – I should have explained that better)